# Maven testCompile

Tags: maven, jenkins, testng

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ HikinaArtf ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
```

It was like this before and everything was working, but I made `mvn clean` and now it looks like this :

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ HikinaArtf ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to ***\target\test-classes



Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: ***\jre1.8.0_45\..\lib\tools.jar -> [Help 1]
```

I don't want to set it up. I just want to turn it off. Is it possible ?

Comment: You seem to target a JRE instead of a JDK, that looks to be the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs often for my project. The error show that tool.jar is missing,
however it is not always the case.
First you can try this solution:

1. Java Build Path >> Libraries
2. JRE System Lybrary >> Edit
3. Installed JREs >> click on my jdk >> edit
4. Add External Jars >> tools.jar

If this does not solve the issue, I will share another solution to it.